# How do I run gdalwarp on a number of csv of coordinates?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have a CSV of Ground Control Points in NAD83 UTM 12N and I need to convert them to WSG84. Is it possible to do this with gdalwarp or something similar?

Comment: gdaltransform comes with gdal, and uses gdal style spatial references:

kyle@kyle-bsu-workstation:~/Desktop/tmp$ gdaltransform --help
Usage: gdaltransform [--help-general]
    [-i] [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]
    [-order n] [-tps] [-rpc] [-geoloc] 
    [-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]* [-output_xy]
    [srcfile [dstfile]]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this conversion with gdalwarp(i think), but it would be way easier to do it using cs2cs

`cat ~/Desktop/coords.csv| sed 's/,/ /' | cs2cs +init=epsg:26912 +to +init=epsg:4326 -f '%.6f'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cs2cs](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs) (part of the proj4 project). You an also load them into QGIS and "Save As" to another coordinate system.